# Why service is shared as one instance across modules?

Tags: angular

I have a root `AppModule` module.

There are two modules `HeaderModule` and `FooterModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [Test2Service],
})
export class HeaderModule {}

@NgModule({
  providers: [Test2Service],
})
export class FooterModule {}
```

As you can see each other has own provider `Test2Service`.

After all I import these modules to main module `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HeaderModule,
    FooterModule,
  ]
```

Why when I make changes in `Test2Service` it has effect in both modules, in components?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do by Test2Service? bcoz if you make any changes in service then it will be reflected in all other instances of the same service.

Comment: Check it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089316/how-to-share-service-between-two-modules-ngmodule-in-angular-not-between-to-c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your modules are lazily loaded, Try `providedIn` any

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'any'
})
```

Comment: providedIn: 'root' is recommended over 'any'. 'any' can lead to unexpected behavior IME.

Comment: @cklimowski they have here different usage and purpose. Check this https://angular.io/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services Services in Angular are singletons meaning there is only one instance. If you are using Angular 6+, you should use the `providedIn: 'root'` decorator and not put it in any `providers` array in any modules. Also, putting the service in multiple provider arrays is not recommended, it should only be provided in one place.

To make a service non-singleton, you can provide it in the component decorator as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428385/7365461)

[This](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f) is a really good blog post. You should check it out.